# Image Map Mouseover highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagemap

I am making a image map for our site navigation manual, I have generated a set of code which a div show on mouse hover...

**EDIT**

The code is all working however I need to highlight the area when mouse hover, is there an easy way to do this, I have tried to use other code however it will interrupt the original java script so the div no longer showing, any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
function showHideDivs(indx) {
  hideDivs();
  oShowHideDivs[indx].style.display = 'block';
}

function hideDivs() {
  for (i = 0; i < oShowHideDivs.length; i++) {
    oShowHideDivs[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  oShowHideDivs = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('div');
  var oMap = document.getElementById('myMap');
  for (i = 0; i < oMap.areas.length; i++) {
    oMap.areas[i].indx = i;
    oMap.areas[i].onmouseover = function() {
      showHideDivs(this.indx);
    }
    oMap.areas[i].onmouseout = hideDivs;
  }
}
```

```css
#container div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="website.jpg" alt="" usemap="#myMap" />
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="home">This is home</div>
  <div id="about">This is about</div>
  <div id="contact">This is contact</div>
</div>
<map name="myMap" id="myMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" href="" alt="home" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="100,0,200,100" href="" alt="about" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,100,100,200" href="" alt="contact" />
    </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below code from W3C school.

```
    <img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

You can refer to the link [HTML map Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Comment: don't see how this code is going to work, the click refer to a new site rather than having the hover over div fixed, also I want to know how do I make the hover area highlighted with border before click on

Comment: Please check this link, http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html#

Answer (score 0):

In the body of your onload function,

```
oShowHideDivs = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('div');
  var oMap = document.getElementById('myMap');
  for (i = 0; i < oMap.areas.length; i++) {
    oMap.areas[i].indx = i;
    oMap.areas[i].onmouseover = function() {
      showHideDivs(this.indx);
    }
```

I would recommend a few small changes.

`oMap.areas[i].indx = 1` does not make sense. `oMap` is a nodelist of `<area>` tags. The `<area>` element does not have an attribute of `indx`. If `oMap` were an array of JavaScript objects, then setting the property of `indx` would be okay.

Looking at this part

```
oMap.areas[i].onmouseover = function() {
      showHideDivs(this.indx);
    }
```

It looks like you are trying to identify a related div by an index.

What would be valid HTML is to give the div a `data-idnx` attribute. It can achieve the same effect like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < oMap.areas.length; i++) {
    var area = oMap.areas[i];

    area.dataset.idnx = i;
    area.onmouseover = MapshowHideDivs(i);
    area.onmouseout = hideDivs();
}
```

So all together

```
// Modern version of window.onload = function()

(function() {
// Variable declarations at the top

// Function declarations
    oShowHideDivs = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('div');
    var oMap = document.getElementById('myMap');

    function showHideDivs(indx) {
      hideDivs();
      oShowHideDivs[indx].style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hideDivs() {
      for (i = 0; i < oShowHideDivs.length; i++) {
        oShowHideDivs[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }


 // Body of the script
    for (i = 0; i < oMap.areas.length; i++) {
        var area = oMap.areas[i];

        area.dataset.idnx = i;
        area.onmouseover = MapshowHideDivs(i);
        area.onmouseout = hideDivs();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I have replaced current javas script with your update code, it's not working, even the hover over div won't show

Comment: It may not be perfect as it is untested. Read the console to see if any errors come up and adjust it to fit your needs.

Comment: sorry if I have made myself unclear, the original code I have posted was working, I am just trying to fix the div when click on hover area instead of change when hover off, I have more information to list in the div for client to see and click, cheers